# Can't find "Download and keep originals"

Tags: icloud, photos

I want to download the photos from my iCloud to my iPhone se, iOS 10.

This is the message I got from apple:

"To download your photos and videos to an iPhone, iPad or iPod touch with iOS 8 or later:
1. Connect to a power source and Wi-Fi.
2.  Go to settings, tap on your account, tap iCloud and then select Photos.
3.  Tap Download and Keep Originals."

I don't have the option "Download and keep originals".

What to do?

Comment: Is this mesage from a web page if so what is the URL?

Comment: It is part of the following mail:

Dear XXXXXX,
iCloud Photo Library has been disabled on all your devices and new photos and videos are no longer being uploaded to iCloud.
There are currently 397 photos and 27 videos in your iCloud Photo Library

Comment: Original format, full resolution versions of your photos and videos are not stored on your devices. You must download your full resolution photos and videos to at least one device before they are deleted from iCloud Photo Library in 30 days.
To download your photos and videos to an iPhone, iPad or iPod touch with iOS 8 or later:
1. Connect to a power source and Wi-Fi.
2. Go to settings, tap on your account, tap iCloud and then select Photos.
3. Tap Download and Keep Originals.

Comment: If your library exceeds the storage space available on your device, you can download your photos and videos to your Mac or PC from iCloud.com.
If you do not want iCloud Photo Library turned off, you can turn it back on directly from your iOS device:
1. Go to Settings and tap iCloud.
2. Select Storage and tap Manage Storage.
3. Select iCloud Photo Library and Undo Delete.
Sincerely,
The iCloud Team

Comment: @Mark please see the above comments

Comment: Are you signed-in to the same iCloud account on your iPhone SE?  Also, what exact iOS 10 version are you using?  See [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264) for additional info.

Comment: Those comments should be edited into your question - assume comments will be deleted